# C++ Getting largest palindrome

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, palindrome

I am trying to get this function to work, it is supposed to take the input string and then change it to all lowercase and then get rid of all of the spaces and punctuation, but I cannot get it to work... I have a part towards the end that is commented out and I do not think that I need it, but I cannot tell...if anyone has any insight on this help would be appreciated!

```
bool PalindromeFinder::isPalindrome(string input) {
//TODO define isPalindrome with the desired functionality
// make new string without the spaces and special characters
//isSpace and isPunct if space or thing then omit to make it a clean string
//need to store largest palindrome so far that was found

// make a string cleanString
string cleanString = "";

//make the string all lowercase
transform(input.begin(), input.end(), input.begin(), ::tolower);

    for ( int i=0; i <= input.length(); i++) {
        char cha = input[cha];

        // now, if there is punctuation or a space, then remove it
        if (ispunct(cha) || isspace(cha)) {
            //remove the punctuation or space
            input.erase(cha) == cleanString;
        }
    }


//        for ( int i=1; i <= input.length(); i++){
//            // check to make sure there are no spaces or punctuation
//        if (!ispunct(cha) && !isspace(cha))
//        {
//            //if there isnt then build the word...ex) e > ex > exa > exam
//            input += cha;
//
//            //this line is for testing
//            cout << "This is my clean string: " << input << endl;
//
//        }
//
//
//    }


//make a empty string to use as a template
    string revString = "";

// for all of the chars in the string, reverse them
    for (int i = cleanString.length()-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        // use this to access array index
        // add the letters back
        revString += cleanString[i];
    }

// now check and make sure that it equals each other...
if (cleanString == revString)
{
    // if it does, return true
    return true;
}
    //otherwise return false
else return false;
}
```

Comment: Please, describe the problem. "getting largest palindrome" isn't enough.

Comment: "input.erase(cha) == cleanString" are you sure you want to be doing double equals here.

Comment: char cha = input[cha]??? input.erase(cha) == cleanString;??? I guess  this is not a real copy/paste of your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `string.erase()` incorrectly.
[Read at the documentation.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase)

`string.erase()` expects either **iterators**, or **indexes**.
You are mistakenly giving it a char which is promoted to an integer and then used as an index.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing faulty loops, all you need are two functions to remove characters and reverse a string.

To erase characters from a `std::string`, you should use [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove):

```
input.erase(std::remove_if(input.begin(), input.end(), [](char c) 
                          { return ::ispunct(c) || isspace(c);}), input.end());
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/honLzh)

Similarly, to reverse a string, you can use [std::reverse](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Answer (score 0):

Make a tmp buffer the size of your input string.  Track input character position in your input string, and output character position in your output buffer.

This is how you'd do it in C.

```
#include <string.h> // for size_t
#include <ctype.h>  // for isalnum

// caller allocates output buffer large as large as input.
// length could be a function parameter, since caller needs to know it anyway.
size_t clean_string(char *out, const char* in)
{
    size_t inpos=0, outpos=0;
    while (in[inpos] != '\0') {
        char c = in[inpos++];
        if (isalnum(c)) // <-- put in whatever logic you want here
            out[outpos++] = c;
    }
    out[outpos] = '\0';
    return outpos;
}
```

This is dead simple, and only ever copies a character once.  It's also arguably easy to read and understand.  There's a good argument to be made for C++ string classes taking care of making sure you never forget the trailing `'\0'`, though.

Erasing a character in the middle of a string has to copy all the following characters over by one.  You're shooting yourself in the foot with C++ by using slow operations probably without realizing, because you just see the `input.erase()` funcion call, not the loop.